# Autofac + Moq: Setup and Verify. (C#)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac

So we have a 3 tier Web API project which I am attempting to implement some tests for.

We are using Autofac as our IoC container, and its integration library with Moq to implement some unit testing.

Start with some code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get()
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {

            // DATA LAYER
            // mock some contact objects up
            var contactsList = new List<CONTACT>
                {
                    new CONTACT { CONTACT_ID = 1, CREATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, UPDATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, CONTACT_TYPE = "Mocked", FORENAME = "Mock1", SURNAME = "Mock1" },
                    new CONTACT { CONTACT_ID = 2, CREATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, UPDATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, CONTACT_TYPE = "Mocked", FORENAME = "Mock2", SURNAME = "Mock2" },
                    new CONTACT { CONTACT_ID = 3, CREATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, UPDATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, CONTACT_TYPE = "Mocked", FORENAME = "Mock3", SURNAME = "Mock3" },
                    new CONTACT { CONTACT_ID = 4, CREATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, UPDATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, CONTACT_TYPE = "Mocked", FORENAME = "Mock4", SURNAME = "Mock4" },
                    new CONTACT { CONTACT_ID = 5, CREATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, UPDATE_DTIME = DateTime.Now, CONTACT_TYPE = "Mocked", FORENAME = "Mock5", SURNAME = "Mock5" },
                }.AsQueryable();

            var contactsSet = new Mock<DbSet<CONTACT>>();
            contactsSet.As<IQueryable<CONTACT>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(contactsList.Provider);
            contactsSet.As<IQueryable<CONTACT>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(contactsList.Expression);
            contactsSet.As<IQueryable<CONTACT>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(contactsList.ElementType);
            contactsSet.As<IQueryable<CONTACT>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(contactsList.GetEnumerator());

            // mock that context
            var mockedContext = new Mock<ExampleEntities>();
            // set up context so that the contactsSet above is returned when queried.
            mockedContext.Setup(c => c.CONTACTS).Returns(contactsSet.Object);

            mock.Provide<IContactsRepository, ContactsRepository>(new TypedParameter(typeof(KCMEntities), mockedContext.Object));
            mock.Provide<IContacts, Contacts>();

            // Instantiate the controller we are performing the test on
            var testController = mock.Create<ContactsController>();

            // act
            ContactListResult contactListResult = testController.Get();

            // assert
            Assert.AreEqual(true, contactListResult.Success);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, contactListResult.ContactList.Count());
            Assert.AreEqual("Mock1", contactListResult.ContactList.First().Forename);
            Assert.AreEqual(1001, contactListResult.ContactList.First().Id); // The businesslogic layer has been doctored to add 1000 to the id...just to test it is passing through this layer..

            mock.Mock<IContactsRepository>().Verify(x => x.GetContacts(), Times.Once());

        }

    }
```

We're not sure if this is really meant to be done but we are trying to write the test to test/mock the action of calling a controller down through all the layers of the application.

The IContactsRepository and the IContacts are the services sitting in the data layer and a business logic layer respectively.

We need to mock the dbcontext at the data layer to return our mocked data, and make sure autofac knows what components to provide for both services when resolving:

```
mock.Provide<IContactsRepository, ContactsRepository>(new TypedParameter(typeof(KCMEntities), mockedContext.Object));
mock.Provide<IContacts, Contacts>();
```

We're setting up the expectation that the mocked context is to be passed into the data layer when it is resolved. This is an overridden constructor on the concrete implementation of the IContactsRepository (tried a non overidden same issues). The default constructor simply news up a new dbcontext, no params.

This seems to work up to a point.

All asserts are fine until we try a verify:

```
mock.Mock<IContactsRepository>().Verify(x => x.GetContacts(), Times.Once());
```

This throws an error:

``` "Unable to cast object of type 'Data.Repositories.ContactsRepository' to type 'Moq.IMocked``1[Data.Interfaces.IContactsRepository]'." ```

Now for obvious reasons we want to use verify to verify certain methods are called on the components/services we have.

We've tried many variations of setup e.g. `mock.Mock>IContacts>().Setup`(.... etc etc, and not managed to work it out/set it up properly.

Essentially we are either doing something basically flawed in trying to test like this, or *hopefully* we are just doing incorrect setup.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you use Moq Except method?

Comment: ideally this should work `new Mock<IMoq>(MockBehavior.Strict)` which you did already except for the behaviour is set to loose.

Comment: *trying to write the test to test/mock the action of calling a controller down through all the layers of the application* - why? What will that prove? You should only be mocking one boundary - the whole point of mocking is that you don't care what is behind that boundary. If you're testing a controller, you should only be mocking the direct dependencies of the controller. At this rate your test will just be a load of fake services that bear no relationship to your actual code.

Comment: You can try creating a mock for IContactsRepository, then setup all used methods/properties from that mock to hook into ContactsRepository, then provide the mock as the implementation instead of ContractsRepository and verify on the mock.